# ASP.Net MVC 4 Areas and view config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've read through so many threads on here and none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

I've had troubles creating areas and finding the associated views. I've created a brand new project with nothing else but the default code and created an area called "Assignment". Within the assignment area I have a controller called "AssignmentDetails" with the corresponding view folder.

When I try and view localhost:1234/AssignmentDetails/ I get the error:  The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

```
~/Views/AssignmentDetails/Index.aspx
~/Views/AssignmentDetails/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/AssignmentDetails/Index.cshtml
~/Views/AssignmentDetails/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

**Globals.asax**
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

```
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth()
```

**AssignmentAreaRegistration**

```
        context.MapRoute( _
            "Assignment_default", _
           "Assignment/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            New With {.action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View for a controller from area Assignment should be in

```
~/Areas/Assignment/Views/ControllerName
```

Comment: Then please show the controller code, including namespace it is in.

Comment: It appears I was missing a namespace :/
Adding that did the trick, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have an area called `Assignment` and `AssignmentDetails` inside that, you'll find the index at this url:

```
localhost:1234/Assignment/AssignmentDetails/Index
```

Comment: That doesn't find anything at all. If I use  localhost:1234/AssignmentDetails/ I get the view not found error.

Comment: Do you have an Index method in your AssignmentDetails controller. If you do, right click within the method and click `Add View` and And click ok. This will add a `.cshtml` view into the correct folder.

Comment: He probably has Index action method, otherwise he would have gotten "resourse not found" error. It is the view file that is not found.

Comment: I have an index method and corresponding view.
If I put a messagebox in there before the return view() I see the messagebox when I access localhost:1234/AssignmentDetails/ then it returns the "view not found error"

Comment: Hm but you need `Assignment` in your url, like this: `localhost:1234/Assignment/AssignmentDetails`

Comment: gideon, you are correct, but not until I added the namespace in my controller!